# Monitor WebLogic using Python

Tags: python, weblogic, monitoring

I want to monitor WebLogic Server running in production box remotely using Python Script from my local workstation. I found that WSLT provides number of commands to monitor Weblogic. I have to idea how to connect to weblogic box 1st and run WSLT scripts. If possible, please share some code examples, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the example
java -cp ${WLS_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.jar weblogic.WLST getWlsValue.py

[image]